# python: parsing XML fields

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, xml

With my below Python3 script, i am able to parse and convert XML records into lists , (by extracting value field out of it).

please help to improve this to print with name ":" value from the XML records.

**for example**: assuming below piece

```
<field name="RecordType" value="RESGJG"/>
<field name="RecordTypeHEC" value="PY"/>
```

getting output

```
RESGJG, PY
```

required output:

```
RecordType:RESGJG, RecordTypeHEC:PY
```

my input file: dummy.xml       (##please note it has two records##every record starts with record source="AJS/SHD")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records>
<record source="AJS/SHD" type="call">
<group name="General">
<field name="RecordType" value="RESGJG"/>
<field name="RecordTypeHEC" value="PY"/>
<field name="NodeID" value="rock.dsjjgds.cm"/>
<field name="SequenceNumber" value="7937973"/>
<field name="StartDate" value="20171049979"/>
<field name="EndDate" value="201704059739793"/>
<field name="CallDuration" value="973979i"/>
<field name="CauseForRecordClosing" value="normal"/>
</group>
<group name="SIP">
<field name="ICID" value="dshhkdhs"/>
<field name="CallID" value="sdidydakyd2133@10.10.10.1"/>
<field name="User-Agent" value="NotPresent"/>
<field name="Request-URI" value="sip:+47668384"/>
<field name="CalledPartyNumber" value="sip:+08779379972"/>
<field name="CallingPartyNumber" value="sip:+07073873772@10.0.0.1"/>
<field name="To" value="sip:+878379739"/>
<field name="From" value="sip:+937973962"/>
</group>
<group name="VPN">
<field name="VPN_NAME_B" value="blshahd"/>
<field name="VPN_Group_B" value="ctr"/>
<field name="B_ExtType" value="part"/>
<field name="B_ISDN" value="7973"/>
<field name="B_SIP" value="67367672"/>
<field name="B_PABXID" value="797397"/>
</group>
</record>
<record source="AJS/SHD" type="call">
<group name="General">
<field name="RecordType" value="MESGJG"/>
<field name="RecordTypeHEC" value="DY"/>
<field name="NodeID" value="rock.dsjjgds.cm"/>
<field name="SequenceNumber" value="7937973"/>
<field name="StartDate" value="20171049979"/>
<field name="EndDate" value="201704059739793"/>
<field name="CallDuration" value="973979i"/>
<field name="CauseForRecordClosing" value="normal"/>
</group>
<group name="SIP">
<field name="ICID" value="dshhkdhs"/>
<field name="CallID" value="sdidydakyd2133@10.10.10.1"/>
<field name="User-Agent" value="NotPresent"/>
<field name="Request-URI" value="sip:+47668384"/>
<field name="CalledPartyNumber" value="sip:+08779379972"/>
<field name="CallingPartyNumber" value="sip:+07073873772@10.0.0.1"/>
<field name="To" value="sip:+878379739"/>
<field name="From" value="sip:+937973962"/>
</group>
<group name="VPN">
<field name="VPN_NAME_B" value="blshahd"/>
<field name="VPN_Group_B" value="ctr"/>
<field name="B_ExtType" value="part"/>
<field name="B_ISDN" value="7973"/>
<field name="B_SIP" value="67367672"/>
<field name="B_PABXID" value="797397"/>
</group>
</record>
</records>
```

and i have already tried below script to parse XML fields and print in list format.

```
import sys
import operator
from functools import reduce
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse("dummy.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
data = []
groups = root.findall('.//group')
for group in groups:
    data.append([f.attrib['value'] for f in group.findall('./field')])
    q = reduce(operator.concat, data)
    s = ", ".join(q)
print(s)
```

getting Output as

```
RESGJG, PY, rock.dsjjgds.cm, 7937973, 20171049979, 201704059739793, 973979i, normal, dshhkdhs, sdidydakyd2133@10.10.10.1, NotPresent, sip:+47668384, sip:+08779379972, sip:+07073873772@10.0.0.1, sip:+878379739, sip:+937973962, blshahd, ctr, part, 7973, 67367672, 797397, MESGJG, DY, rock.dsjjgds.cm, 7937973, 20171049979, 201704059739793, 973979i, normal, dshhkdhs, sdidydakyd2133@10.10.10.1, NotPresent, sip:+47668384, sip:+08779379972, sip:+07073873772@10.0.0.1, sip:+878379739, sip:+937973962, blshahd, ctr, part, 7973, 67367672, 797397
```

required output:

```
RecordType:RESGJG, RecordTypeHEC:PY, NodeID:rock.dsjjgds.cm, SequenceNumber:7937973, StartDate:20171049979, EndDate:201704059739793, CallDuration:973979i, CauseForRecordClosing:normal, ICID:dshhkdhs, CallID:sdidydakyd2133@10.10.10.1, User-Agent:NotPresent, Request-URI:sip:+47668384, CalledPartyNumber:sip:+08779379972, CallingPartyNumber:sip:+07073873772@10.0.0.1, To:sip:+878379739, From:sip:+937973962, VPN_NAME_B:blshahd, VPN_Group_B:ctr, B_ExtType:part, B_ISDN:7973, B_SIP:67367672, B_PABXID:797397,

RecordType:MESGJG, RecordTypeHEC:DY, NodeID:rock.dsjjgds.cm, SequenceNumber:7937973, StartDate:20171049979, EndDate:201704059739793, CallDuration:973979i, CauseForRecordClosing:normal, ICID:dshhkdhs, CallID:sdidydakyd2133@10.10.10.1, User-Agent:NotPresent, Request-URI:sip:+47668384, CalledPartyNumber:sip:+08779379972, CallingPartyNumber:sip:+07073873772@10.0.0.1, To:sip:+878379739, From:sip:+937973962, VPN_NAME_B:blshahd, VPN_Group_B:ctr, B_ExtType:part, B_ISDN:7973, B_SIP:67367672, B_PABXID:797397,
```

Please help me

Comment: You only get `f.attrib['value']`. You need to get also `f.attrib['name']`... and make `data` a dict because you wanted a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code only fetches the `value` attribute, it completly ignores the `name`.

Also, using `reduce` is somewhat an overkill.

```
groups = root.findall('.//group')
for group in groups:
    print(', '.join('{}: {}'.format(field.attrib['name'], field.attrib['value']) for field in group.findall('./field')))
    print()
```

Will output:

```
RecordType: RESGJG, RecordTypeHEC: PY, NodeID: rock.dsjjgds.cm, SequenceNumber: 7937973, StartDate: 20171049979, EndDate: 201704059739793, CallDuration: 973979i, CauseForRecordClosing: normal

ICID: dshhkdhs, CallID: sdidydakyd2133@10.10.10.1, User-Agent: NotPresent, Request-URI: sip:+47668384, CalledPartyNumber: sip:+08779379972, CallingPartyNumber: sip:+07073873772@10.0.0.1, To: sip:+878379739, From: sip:+937973962

VPN_NAME_B: blshahd, VPN_Group_B: ctr, B_ExtType: part, B_ISDN: 7973, B_SIP: 67367672, B_PABXID: 797397

RecordType: MESGJG, RecordTypeHEC: DY, NodeID: rock.dsjjgds.cm, SequenceNumber: 7937973, StartDate: 20171049979, EndDate: 201704059739793, CallDuration: 973979i, CauseForRecordClosing: normal

ICID: dshhkdhs, CallID: sdidydakyd2133@10.10.10.1, User-Agent: NotPresent, Request-URI: sip:+47668384, CalledPartyNumber: sip:+08779379972, CallingPartyNumber: sip:+07073873772@10.0.0.1, To: sip:+878379739, From: sip:+937973962

VPN_NAME_B: blshahd, VPN_Group_B: ctr, B_ExtType: part, B_ISDN: 7973, B_SIP: 67367672, B_PABXID: 797397
```

Comment: Hello.. thanks for reply.. i am new to programming, and not very sure about mentioning "dict format" is proper way to communicate or not.. But my required output is same as mentioned above.

Comment: Your first code is fine,only problem i have is that i need to print all fields under dict {}, separately per record/ means this dummy.xml has 2 records.. may i get help to print them line by line separately. (like i mentioned in required output)

Comment: @SSK please decide the required output. It started from a dict, went to a string now it's a dict again?

Comment: Sorry.. i didnt see updated answer before i sent my comment.. but thanks.. it helps and fulfilled my requirement.

Comment: THANKS A LOT.. i got required output from updated code above.